# How do you install Open CV 3.0 for Mac 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV 3 (bleeding edge) from the master branch on github.

What I've tried so far:

- Following the general linux instructions, which broadly are:
- Clone
- Run `cmake`
- Run `make -j8`
- `sudo make install`

My system has Python 2.7.5. It appears to build correctly, but on import to Python it causes `Segmentation fault: 11`. Other posts indicate that this is likely because of an incompatible version of Python. I have checked the cmake scripts and it searches for 2.7.x, so it *should* be fine.

Any tips/suggestions?